Is it correct to feed rnn longer context than it had during training?
rnn's provide the ability to generate infinity number of tokens. But if I train it with a time length of 25, will it perform well when the length of the context in reference is 50?
it seemed to me that if i cut the context while generating (e.g sentence = sentence[-25:]) to the length that rnn learned from, then its perfomance is slightly better. Am i correct or not?
